# Confused by querySelector()

Tags: javascript

Just looking for some clarification. **W3** says that a CSS selector is required for using the `querySelector()` method but this *Mozilla* tutorial is using an `img` tag:

```
var myImage = document.querySelector('img');
```

I assume you can use `querySelector()` on HTML tags?

Comment: html tags are selectors

Comment: a HTML tag name is just one type of CSS selector, so yes. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Selectors might make useful reading

Comment: If you were on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll already, all you had to do was follow the link inside of “This string must be a valid [CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) string” …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`img` *is* a CSS selector. It's an element type, one of the [many different types of selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) that also includes classes and IDs and attributes.

Answer (score 1):

These are called [`Type selectors`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Type_selectors)

> The CSS type selector matches elements by ***node name***. In other words, it selects all elements of the given type within a document.

Answer (score 0):

The type selector `img` selects img elements. It isn't in an HTML document surrounded by `<` and `>` so it isn't a tag itself.

See [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#type-selectors)

> A type selector is the name of a document language element type
>   written using the syntax of CSS qualified names [CSS3NAMESPACE]. A
>   type selector represents an instance of the element type in the
>   document tree.
>
> Example:
>
> The following selector represents an h1 element in the document tree:
>
> ```
> h1
> ```